WhatsApp app-review : call to /v1/account generates Unknown path components: /account
The "App Review" process requires registering your phone number using a verified certificate (see screenshot).

1. Obtain the phone certificate
I obtained the certificate through this link: WhatsApp Manager > Phone numbers
https://business.facebook.com/latest/whatsapp_manager/phone_numbers/?business_id=1234&asset_id=1224&nav_ref=whatsapp_manager&tab=phone-numbers&psp_linking_success=0&is_from_mbs=1
2. WhatsApp requires to register the phone using an /v1/account endpoint
The WhatsApp system requests that you send a POST request to the /v1/account endpoint, as described in the WhatsApp Business Platform > On-Premises API > Reference
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/on-premises/reference/account/
3. Attempt to call the /v1/account endpoint
I attempted to call the endpoint using this URL:
https://graph.facebook.com/v1/account
The body of the request follows the format defined in the API documentation 2.
Here is the body of the POST request:
POST /v1/account

{
    "cc": "COUNTRY_CODE",
    "phone_number": "PHONE_NUMBER_WITHOUT_COUNTRY_CODE",
    "method": "sms" or "voice",
    "cert": "VERIFIED_NAME_CERT_IN_BASE64",
    "pin": "EXISTING_6_DIGIT_PIN"  # required if two-step verification is enabled
}

4. Error message got after calling /v1/account endpoint
I get the follow error
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Unknown path components: /account",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 2500,
        "fbtrace_id": "1234"
    }
}



https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/on-premises/reference/account/: "We are sunsetting On-Premises API. This endpoint can no longer be used to register business phone numbers and now returns the following error: ..." - different error there than you are getting - but that probably doesn't change much about the fact, that they don't let you use this endpoint any more.

@c3roe , I agree with you BUT that is the link provided by Facebook/WhatsApp!
What is the solution?

The /v1/account endpoint is not working because this is the endpoint to use when you use the on-premise WhatsApp server
I guess that the correct endpoint is {PHONE_NUMBER_ID}/register
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/reference/registration/
PS: WhatsApp documentation leads mistakenly to the /v1/account :-(

$ch = curl_init();

$data = array(
    "cc" => "COUNTRY_CODE",
    "phone_number" => "PHONE_NUMBER_WITHOUT_COUNTRY_CODE",
    "method" => "sms", // or "voice"
    "cert" => "VERIFIED_NAME_CERT_IN_BASE64",
    "pin" => "EXISTING_6_DIGIT_PIN" // required if two-step verification is enabled
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://graph.facebook.com/v1/account");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json'
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
} else {
    echo $response;
}

curl_close($ch);

Exact same thing. Code above results in:
{"error":{"message":"Unknown path components: \/account","type":"OAuthException","code":2500,"fbtrace_id":"APrxxxxxxxxxxxxxlxux"}}


I think that the new endpoint to use is
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/reference/registration/

Correct. I wanted to write here back the same.
Starting process from scratch and flowing WhatsApp Cloud API instruction helped !!! :)

now you should do a POST request to:
https://graph.facebook.com/{{Version}}/{{Phone-Number-ID}}/register
EDIT:
and the body:
{
    "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
    "pin": "<your-6-digit-pin>"
}

do not forget to add your bearer token before making the request!
